# Extend an application with webpack like requireJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, requirejs

**Existing App:**
My application is using require.js. 
Benefit of my application is that other people can extend my application via writing 3rd party plugins using require.js

For example: (a 3rd party plugin registration)

`// registering a new plugin
 {
  url:'#new-page-url',
  js:'plugin-folder/new-page-url.js'
}`

So when `#new-page-url` is hit anywhere, requirejs consumes js file from `plugin-folder/new-page-url.js`

Please note that after I compile my application, it does not include third party source as they can be fetched on the fly with requriejs

**Question:**
I have been looking into webpack and since it compiles everything before distribution (bundle.js as starting file).How can a third party plugin work on the fly like above example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please note that after I compile my application, it does not include third party source as they can be fetched on the fly with requriejs

Yes, that's the problem.

I'm in a situation similar to yours where a large application of mine written as a collection of AMD modules can load editing modes at runtime, which are also AMD modules. The modes are not generally bundled with the application.

AFAIK it is not possible to replicate *only with Webpack* the possibility of doing the equivalent of a RequireJS' `require([a])` where `a` is a variable whose value cannot be known at build time but is determined at run time. (And for the benefit of readers who may not be familiar with RequireJS, I'll add that yes, I do mean the first argument to be `[a]` and not just `a`. RequireJS makes a distinction between the two.)

Webpack needs to know at build time which modules it is going to bundle together. ("Needs to know" means it needs to know the name *and* find the module's source.) So it does not support dynamically loading modules that only get to be known at runtime. If you read the documentation, or tutorial, you'll run into discussions of dynamic loading with Webpack but these do not allow doing the equivalent of the `require([a])` case. Webpack can split a bundle into chunks and load chunks as needed but for this to work, Webpack still needs to know ahead of time the whole set of modules it is ever going to need. *This does not allow loading at runtime a module that was unknown at build time.* There's also `require.context`, but while it allows you to determine at run time *which specific module* you want, the set from which the module comes is *determined at build time*. If at build time you know that you're going to be using one of A, B, C, that's fine. But if you don't know at build time the name of your module, or cannot feed its source to Webpack, you're out of luck.

This being said, it should be possible to build your application's core with Webpack and have this core perform direct calls to a module loader like RequireJS or SystemJS. This is the direction I'm moving into with my own application but I've not crossed that bridge yet.

Comment: you saved me a lot of time. I like your solution but I would just stick with requirejs since I need to keep in mind 3rd party devs and things will be much simpler if everyone is on same set of source plugins

Comment: For example: in webpack, jquery would be added when compiled. But for a 3rd party dev, he would be adding it again, since he cant do imports from webpacks. Yes he can check window.$ and what not but thats not clean

Comment: I would do love to know if I want to go with Babel, should i be using requirejs or someother module loader ?? Keeping in mind on the fly loading of 3rd party modules

Comment: My plan to solve the issue of plugins needing jQuery is to make jQuery available through the facade that the app core will expose to plugins. In my opinion, the choice of module loader, or loader vs bundler, is mostly project-dependent. Going with RequireJS makes some things easier: each and every module is available to every module, so a plugin can load a third-party module without having to go through your app core. However, RequireJS exposes all modules to everyone, which hinders you if you want to keep some modules "private". I find this to be a problem in my application.

Comment: thankx for your input. I see you are in same boat as me. In my case, 3rd party devs have to apply to get a working copy of product and develop on it. In this case, do you think requireJs makes sense